# using python 3 turtle onscreenclick method cant return value

Tags: python, python-turtle

Modifying my first python turtle program (it works) with the onclicks method failed.
I cant get it to return the values for use outside the function.
It is clear I need to better understand scope and variables.
But still cant return (I used return in a little test program ok).
Heres my code that works other than return.

```
import turtle
screen=turtle.Screen();t1=turtle.Turtle()
x1=y1=x2=y2=0;clicks=0

def mouse_click(x,y): 
    global clicks,x1,y1,x2,y2

    clicks = clicks + 1
    t1.penup()
    screen.onscreenclick(None)
    t1.goto(x, y)
    screen.onscreenclick(mouse_click)
    if clicks==2:#bypass clicks==1 as automatic at start giving unwanted 0,0
        x1 = t1.xcor()
        y1 = t1.ycor()
    if clicks==3:
        x2 = t1.xcor()
        y2 = t1.ycor()
    if clicks==4:
        turtle.exitonclick()
    
    print("inside x1 y1 x2 y2",clicks,x1,y1,x2,y2)
    return clicks,x1,y1,x2,y2

#MAIN

#get clicks screen.onscreenclick(mouse_click)

#get returned coordinates for further use - doesnt work! clicks,x1,y1,x2,y2=mouse_click(x1,y1) print("outside clicks x1 y1 x2 y2",clicks,x1,y1,x2,y2)

#end screen.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks so much. I will study your comments. Re formatting, I just cut and pasted from my code file so thought it would go across ok. Your neat code runs fine but never exits so cant then go and use coordinates outside the function. I want to use the function in a much larger program so need to get the coordinates out and end capturing clicks, but without exiting the program.

Answer (score 0):

*You need to put 4 spaces before each line, to retain formatting.*

It seems that you are trying to generate a couple of XY coordinate pairs.

It's not that there's an inner and an outer loop to callbacks.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_(computer_programming)

This is what you've bound to `onscreenclick()`.  You need to either take into account for the number of clicks, and change what happens within your callback from that point...

or completely redefine your callback, if that's absolutely needed.  `turtle.onscreenclick(new_callback_function, add=False)`

```
#! /usr/bin/python3

from turtle import Turtle, Screen
turtle, screen = Turtle(), Screen()

##~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

clicks, x1, y1, x2, y2 = 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
turtle.penup()

def click_callback( x, y ):
    global clicks, x1, y1, x2, y2
    clicks = clicks +1

    ##  modulo:  divide by 2, check the remainder
    if clicks %2 == 1:  ##  odd step
        x1, y1 = x, y
        turtle.goto( x1, y1 )

        print( f"odd click {clicks}:  {x1}, {y1},  {x2}, {y2}" )
    else:  ##  even step
        x2, y2 = x, y
        turtle.goto( x2, y2 )

        print( f"even click {clicks}:  {x1}, {y1},  {x2}, {y2}" )
    ##  return clicks, x1, y1, x2, y2

screen.onscreenclick( click_callback )
screen.mainloop()

##  eof  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: Your solution is on the mark but you retained the OP's `return` statement giving a false impression that something gets returned.  The code that invokes the callback will ignore the returned result.  Best not to confuse the situation and leave it out.